# Remove almost parallels NetworkX shortest path

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path, osmnx

I generated a path between locations A and B with the constrain of locations that I have to pass throw them or at close to them so the route looks like: `A -> c1 -> c2 - > B`, even though it is not the shortest path.

I used `for path in nx.all_shortest_paths(UG, source=l1_node_id, target=l2_node_id,weight = 'wgt'):`

when `'wgt'` is the distance of the edge/driving speed in this road.

I generated a list of lists where each inner list is the node_id for example:

```
l_list = [
    [n11,n12,n13,n14....]
    [n21,n22,n23,n24....]
         ..
    ]
```

and on the map, its looks like:(the markers are the beginning of each route and I also colored them with different color)
[image]

I want to change it to one route but as you can see there are some splits like the green and the red, some common sequences(which I can handle) and the second problem is the beginning of the blue route\end of the black one which is unimportant.

I can't just remove the red route because it supposed to be a generic algorithm and I don't know even where it will happen again during this route.

I do have timestamps of each marker but it just says that I have been close to this area. (it is locations of cellular antennas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you gonna need to define what is "almost parallel" more concisely, or more formally, you need to define a similarity function.

## Choosing a similarity/distance function

There are plenty of ways to define a similarity function, here is one of them

### Resample

Assuming each node `n_i` has an x and y coordinates `(n_i_x,n_i_y)`. 
You can resample the points on the `x`-axis, such that the new points are sampled at `1km`.

Then, for each 2 routes, you'll can sum the difference in the `y` axis.
Use this distance in order to cluster routes.

### Other ideas

- [Earth mover distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance)
- Jaccard (~ % of common nodes)

## Clustering

Once you defined a `similarity` function, you can use a distance based clstering algorithm, I recommend using [sklearn's agglomerative clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html).

After the clustering is done, all you have left to do is to choose one route from each cluster.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, there are not really two routes, as you can see I have three paths, each one starting from the marker and colored black, red and blue. My goal is to convert it to one path from the beginning of the black path (left up) to the end of the blue path(right up). each path is a different set of nodes ids with maybe some common nodes between different paths. So maybe I didn;t understand you but distance function can help me?

Comment: yup, I got it. Given 2 routes, define a similarity function d(r1, r2), then run it on all the routes. you got a square matrix of shape (N,N) where N is the number of routes. Feed this distance matrix into a clustering algorithm and choose one representative from each cluster.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean. Thank you

Comment: I thought I did, how do I do it?